# How does a computer signal via VGA for the monitor to sleep

Tags: vga

Could somebody please explain how a "modern" monitor is told to sleep.  I need to know this for a VGA with blue connector, i.e. it has DDC.  I've heard that the sync stops.  If true, which sync?

Reason for asking: I'm trying to connect to an industrial single-board computer that has a 2 x 5 pin VGA header.  I've made a cable that matches the documented pinout, but the company doesn't output the +5V that should be on pin 9.  And the monitor stays asleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the 15 pin VGA connector, you can signal to the monitor to go into standby (sleep, energy saver, etc) mode by sending the appropriate signals:

> VESA DPMS power saving VESA has defined a standard method for computer to tell monitor when to go to power saving mode. This power saving mode is controlled by changing the sync signals according the table below:
>
> ```
>             NORMAL STANDBY SUSPENDED  OFF 
> H-sync        On    Off       On      Off 
> V-sync        On    On        Off     Off 
> Power level  100%   80%      <30W     <8W
> ```

(source: [ePanorama: VGA analog display connector](http://www.epanorama.net/documents/pc/vga_bd15.html))